# Dojo has/sniff and OS detection

Tags: javascript, dojo

Do these dojo API's have any O.S detection or 32 64bit OS detection? Or would I have to incorporate that with standard JS? I cannot find any references to OS detection in the documentation for Dojo.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

According to the list of [feature names](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/has.html#dojo-1-7-feature-names), there are tests for:

- `dojo/_base/sniff.js , mac`
- `dojo/_base/sniff.js , ios`
- `util/build/main.js , is-windows`

This seems to imply there is some level of OS detection. You might want to look in these specific files for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, there is no detection for unix or linux O/S. Plenty of browser support in these two though.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately you would have to lump these in an `other` category. But depending on what you are trying to do, you can probably get OS server-side - for example, by analyzing the browser's User Agent string.

Comment: I am going to detect OS and 32bit vs. 64bit with vanilla JS and then use Dojo for all other has/sniff features.